# Xcode - Animating with PNG sequence

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, after-effects

I have made an animation with After Effect and added it to my Xcode project as a PNG sequence. This leave me with a folder with 164 images, i am animating with a timer. How is that for the app performance? And could i add more animations like this without any problem?

Answer (score 4):

if its images, 
first get those images in an array

```
 @IBOutlet weak var animatingImageView: UIImageView!
var imageList = [UIImage]()
```

now call function

```
func playAnimation() {
    self.animatingImageView.animationImages = imageList
    self.animatingImageView.animationDuration = 2.0
    self.animatingImageView.startAnimating()
}
```

you can use

```
self.animatingImageView. animationRepeatCount
```

for repeat count,

and also, if you want to stop it after some time interval, do it with a timer, and on timer completion

```
self.animatingImageView.stopAnimating()
```

for better performance:

try using image of size close to the imageview

try using cached image

try making image opaque

Comment: So i should write an array of 164 images? :O